# How to send email with Boldon James classification

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, email

Is there a way to integrate [Boldon James classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boldon_James) into send email function in .net core (c#)?

Here is my code for sending email :

```
public string SendEmail(string subject, string body, string sender, string receiver, string filePath = null)
{

    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(Configuration["SmtpClient"]); 
    client.Port = Convert.ToInt32(Configuration["SmtpPort"]); //587
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = Convert.ToInt32(Configuration["UseDefaultCredential"]) == 1 ? true : false;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Configuration["SmtpUsername"]))
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Configuration["SmtpUsername"].Trim(), Configuration["SmtpPassword"].Trim()); 
    client.EnableSsl = Convert.ToInt32(Configuration["SmtpEnableSSL"]) == 1 ? true : false;
    client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;

    MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
    mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(sender);
    mailMessage.To.Add(receiver);
    mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
    mailMessage.Subject = subject;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath))
    {
        mailMessage.AlternateViews.Add(getEmbeddedImage(filePath, body));
        Attachment attachments = new Attachment(filePath);
        //attachments.ContentDisposition.Inline = true;
        mailMessage.Attachments.Add(attachments);
    }
    else
    {
        mailMessage.Body = body;
    }
    client.Send(mailMessage);

    return "OK";
 }
```

Comment: its not clear what `Boldon James Classification` is